# How do we detect audio end point changing in a Windows Store app?

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-mobile

For WINDOW UNIVERSAL APP, I want to detect whener audio end point is changed.

- For Windows Mobile App, I used Windows.Phone.Media.Devices.AudioRoutingManager to get the callback and do audio stream routing.
- For Windows Desktop App, MMDevice API may come in hand.
- For Windows Store App, I don't know how to get this. How to detect this?

  Any help and useful suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long searching and making reveral test, I think creating a DeviceWatcher is the most relevant solution for this. I tried it and get notifications whenever any headphone/mic is added or removed as well.

*After creating the watcher, you will receive the following notifications for any device that matches your provided criteria.*

- *Add notification when a new device is added*.
- *Update notification when
  a property you are interested in is changed.*
- *Remove notification when
  a device is no longer available or no longer matches your filter.*

This is the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/enumerate-devices?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#enumerate-and-watch-devices) refer to it.

Answer (score 3):

In UWP, we can use [MediaDevice.DefaultAudioRenderDeviceChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.devices.mediadevice.defaultaudiorenderdevicechanged) event to detect default audio render device is changed. This event contains a [DefaultAudioRenderDeviceChangedEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.devices.defaultaudiorenderdevicechangedeventargs.aspx) argument. With its [Id](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.devices.defaultaudiorenderdevicechangedeventargs.id.aspx) property, we can get the ID of the newly selected default audio render device. Once we have the device ID, we can use [DeviceInformation.CreateFromIdAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br225425.aspx) method to get [DeviceInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.aspx). This class allows access to well-known device properties as well as additional properties specified during device enumeration. For more info, please see [Device information properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/device-information-properties). And following is a simple sample:

```cs
MediaDevice.DefaultAudioRenderDeviceChanged += MediaDevice_DefaultAudioRenderDeviceChanged;

private async void MediaDevice_DefaultAudioRenderDeviceChanged(object sender, DefaultAudioRenderDeviceChangedEventArgs args)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{args.Id} : {args.Role}");

    var device = await DeviceInformation.CreateFromIdAsync(args.Id);

    //TODO
}
```

Besides, we can get all available audio endpoints by using [MediaDevice.GetAudioRenderSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.media.devices.mediadevice.getaudiorenderselector) method with [DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br225433) method like:

```cs
var outputDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(MediaDevice.GetAudioRenderSelector());
```

For more info, please see [Output to a specific audio endpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer#output-to-a-specific-audio-endpoint).

Comment: Hi @Jay, it seems your suggestion is a good solution. But have you tried this for Windows Phone Store App? Does it work? For me, I tried with DeviceWatcher and it works well.

Comment: @LuongMinhHiep `DefaultAudioRenderDeviceChanged` is a universal API, it should be able to work on Mobile device. And I've tested on Lumia 640, it works well.

Comment: @JayZuo Your answer helped me ! However, I experienced an unwanted behaviour due to making the function asynchronous. For my case, when I remove a USB speaker, the callback is triggered twice (I have some monitors connected to my laptop) and the two callbacks are for my integrated speaker or the monitor, weird behaviour. Because the callback definition is asynchronous, the second callback is triggered before the end of the first one messing up my code logic and triggering exceptions. Just wanted to flag that risk =)